# Acts As Taggable On: translate tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, translation, acts-as-taggable-on, globalize2

I'm working with RoR and I was wondering how can I translate Acts As Taggable On tags without having to manually insert it every time I use a tag again?

Example:
I have a Post (title and body in English) and I create it with tags "shoes, dress, beauty".
I've title and body translated to Japanese in a text file, so I just need to copy/paste them (I'm using Globalize2 plugin to manage translations).
Then I need to add Japanese tags, so I search for translation and add it.
Now I know how to write these three words to Japanese, but I don't want to have to translate them every time I use the same tag.
Next time I create a post with the "shoes" tag, I want that the Japanese version already has the translated term.

What do you suggest? Abandon Acts As Taggable On and create a custom Tags model with a habtm relationship with Post? Subclass the Acts As Taggable On model?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to simply create your own controller, views and routes and CRUD tags as you see fit by adding whatever fields you require to the db table with no need to subclass the tag model. Personally unless there's some fancy cloud calculation or so forth with this plugin I would roll your own as it's pretty basic. It would also be a good exercise to look through the plugin and gain an understanding of its functionality.